# My icon is too big how do I make it smaller? | Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, icons, themes

i've looked around in the settings but nothing to minimize it. [My Icons in Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW7wc.png)

I hope in the future there will be icon settings.so that users can set it by themselves.

i hope someone can help me , thanks